# mod_rewrite, user dir

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have software with student, teacher and admin part. I want to allow teacher to choose their web address such as `http://mydomain.com/teacher1`, `http://mydomain.com/teacher2` etc.

How can I use this mod_rewrite for that? This part is working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule username teacher/
```

but not when I have some link in teacher dir such as `teacher/training.php` browser open `index.php` page in `teacher/dir` instead of `training.php`.

Comment: I'm sorry I really don't understand your question. Could you please explain what you want (= starting URL), how it should be rewritten internally on the server side, and if you have errors, please write the URLs that are problematic.

Comment: You'd probably get better responses at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com since they specialize in this kind of thing.  I've voted to migrate to there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_rewrite reads all of the path and modifies it all. The format is: "RewriteRule *pattern substitution*" ([Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule))

"Pattern" can be a substring and anything that matches that substring will be rewritten, but "substitution" is the *full path*.

Assuming that you want "username" to only match at the start, and assuming that all locations under it must be rewritten, what you need is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^username(/(.*))? teacher$1
```

That will ignore "username" but append the rest of the path on the end, so `http://example.com/username/training.php` would show the content for (but not change the address to) `http://example.com/teacher/training.php`. If you want it to do a full redirect so that the URL changes, add `[R=301]` at the end of the `RewriteRule` line.